# Sharepoint list columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Is it possible to create a SharePoint column based on choice (definition) that when selected populates the rating on another column?

I will need to add sum of all scores:

[image]

Thanks a million!

Comment: Do you want to store multiple definitions for each question? or you will be adding multiple list items for each definition?

Comment: yes the defintions will be stored. For example, on number 1, there will be three definitions.

Comment: on secodn question, the definitions are:
Minimal
Moderate
Significant. 
Ratings always 0-3-9

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auto-populate values in *Rating*, you can create the *Rating* column as a calculated column, and then use the [**IF** function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca) to return values.

Here is a sample formula for your reference:

```
=IF([Definition]="1-200 people", 0,
    IF([Definition]="201-800 people",3,
        IF([Definition]="> 800 people",9,""
    )
)
```

[image]